# IllegalStateException while trying create NativeQuery with EntityManager

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have been getting this annoying exception while trying to create a native query with my entity manager.  The full error message is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.model.OneToManyEntity2@61f3b3b.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:313)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:441)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:967)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:521)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
```

The actual code that triggers the error is:

```
    Query query;
    query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(RecordID,'-',-1) as Decimal)) FROM `QueriedEntityTable`");
    String recordID = (query.getSingleResult() == null ?
            null :
            query.getSingleResult()
                 .toString());
```

This is being executed with an EntityTransaction in the doTransaction part.  The part that is getting me with this though is that this is the first code to be executed within the doTransaction method, simplified below to:

```
updateOneToManyEntity1();
updateOneToManyEntity2();
entityManager.merge(parentEntity);
```

The entity it has a problem with "OneToManyEntity1" isn't even the table I'm trying to create the query on.  I'm not doing any persist or merge up until this point either, so I'm also not sure what is supposedly causing it to be out of sync.  The only database work that's being done up until this code is executed is just pulling in data, not changing anything.  The foreign keys are properly set up in the database.

I'm able to get rid of this error by doing as it says and marking these relationships as Cascade.PERSIST, but then I get a MySQLContrainstraViolationException on the query.getSingleResult() line. My logs show that its doing some INSERT queries right before this, so it looks like its reaching the EntityManager.merge part of my doTransaction method, but the error and call stack point to a completely different part of the code.

Using EclipseLink (2.6.1), Glassfish 4, and MySQL.  The entitymanager is using RESOURCE_LOCAL with all the necessary classes listed under the persistence-unit tag and exclude-unlisted-classes is set to false.

Edit: So some more info as I'm trying to work through this.  If I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the transaction and then execute entityManager.clear() through IntelliJ's "Evaluate Expression" tool, everything works fine at least the first time through.  Without it, I get an error as it tries to insert empty objects into the table.

Edit #2: I converted the nativeQuery part into using the Criteria API and this let me actually make it through my code so I could find where it was unintentionally adding in a null object to my entity list.  I'm still just confused as to why the entity manager is caching these errors or something to the point that creating a native query is breaking because its still trying to insert bad data.  Is this something I'd need to call EntityManager.clear() before doing each time? Or am I supposed to call this when there is an error in the doTransaction method?

Comment: Where did you place you transaction boundary?

Comment: I'm trying to read up on that some now.  Not sure that I have it set I guess or I'm misunderstanding the concept.  I'm getting a transaction from the entity manager with EntityManager.getTransaction() and then calling .begin(), .doTransaction(), and then .committ() on success or .rollback() for failure.  Since its a Resource_Local persistence context, I don't think I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reworking the code and setting this aside, I stumbled on at least part of the answer to my question.  My issue was caused by the object being persisted prior to the transaction starting.  So when I was entering my transaction, it first tried to insert/update data from my entity objects and threw an error since I hadn't set the values of most of the non-null columns. I believe this is the reason I was getting the cascade errors and I'm positive this is the source of the random insert queries I saw being fired off at the beginning of my transaction.  Hope this helps someone else avoid a lot of trouble.